# Meaning of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code

Tags: google-geocoding-api

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#StatusCodes
 states: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" indicates that you are over your quota.

Is this same code returned when the 2500 per day limit is reached AND when the rate is exceeded?

Comment: Today in my testing I am starting to receive OVER_QUERY_LIMIT consistently in spite of adding more to the delay each iteration. I did not think I had exceeded the daily limit.

Comment: Say, folks. I can't figure this one out. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Since nobody here seems to know the answer to this question, where else can I go?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is the same for per second and per day limit.
Read the following to figure out which limit is reached, this is as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits
"Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second."